# Downloaded module with Anaconda, but it's not found in Pycharm environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, geohashing, site-packages

I successfully downloaded 'geohash' module using Anaconda.  I confirmed it works by testing a line of code in Jupyter notebook.  However, in Pycharm, it cannot find the geohash module.

I see the module 'geohash' clearly is in my Anaconda site-packages folder.

[image]

I then opened a new python file in Pycharm, and selected "New Conda Environment" as the Project interpreter.  You can see the file's interpreter is Anaconda Project Default (Python 3.7) :

[image]

[image]

And yet, there is no 'geohash' module in the venv in Pycharm, and the module cannot be found:

[image]

I'm confused as to why this is so.  I would assume all my modules installed with Anaconda would transfer over once the project interpreter is set to Anaconda Python 3.7.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your pycharm is using the GeoHash env inside conda. Can you make sure that the library is installed within that env using `conda list -n GeoHash`. My guess is that you're creating a new env at the start of the project and the library does not exist in that env

Comment: razdi: good call.  It is not in there.  If I copy and paste the geohash module into : C:\Anaconda\envs\GeoHash\Lib\site-packages  It still doesn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new environment with `conda`, only the default packages are installed at the beginning. When you created the Geohash environments, it was created with only the default packages conda comes with, and geohash is not a part of that.

You would need to install the geohash package to your particular environment using:

```
# Install pip in your environment
conda install -n GeoHash pip

# activate your environment
conda activate GeoHash

# Install the package
pip install Geohash
```

you can read more about managing environments [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I have no idea why.  First off, the package in question is "geohash", not "Geohash".  So I'm not sure why this worked, but it did.  Also, what does the -n mean in conda install?  And what exactly is the GeoHash environment?  Is that something I created in Pycharm, or Anaconda?  Thanks.

Comment: In the second image you provided, look at the Python Interpreter. It points to the env you created in step one and has given it a name `GeoHash` as shown in the brackets. So I installed pip in that env, then activated it. The last install statement was taken from the [GeoHash](https://pypi.org/project/Geohash/) page.

Comment: I realised you might be working with the `python-geohash` package. If you need that, you would only need to change the last step to install that library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of PyCharm you are using. I think you should choose to use existing environment and point to the environment (could be the conda default) where you installed the package. IIUC, choosing "New Environment" would create a new conda environment which does not have your package.